# Adding cocos2d-x to an existing Android project

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have an Android project and would like to add the cocos2d-x Android library to it. As far as documentation/online resources goes, it looks like this just can't happen easily and you need to use their create-android-project as these [instructions](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started) detail. This creates a rather odd file hierarchy where cocos2d-x is at the root and my app-specific files are buried deep within this folder. For consistency and convention, I'd like to be able to put the cocos2d-x library in a 3rd party library folder and include it and use it.

Has anyone had any luck adding the cocos2d-x library to an existing Android project. If so, some steps would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to said with "an existing Android project" ? An android project with cocos2d-x libraries already added in eclipse? or without them? or code?

Comment: I want to add the cocos2d-x library to it. I have a project without the cocos2d-x library currently.

Comment: Since version 2.0.3 (2012-09-26), you must include cocos2d-x libraries manually on Eclipse. Try use hello world, and include cocos2d-x from 3rd party library folder